# A question about quadratic polynomials with complex roots.

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x) =x^2+p^x+q$ be a second degree polynomial, all of whose coefficients are real numbers (but not necessarily real algebraic numbers). If $f(x)$ has no real roots, can the (smallest) field F which contains all the roots of $f(x)$, ever be "formally real"? In other words, can a finite sum of squares of elements of F never be equal to zero unless all those elements are equal to zero? It is not hard to show that the answer is "NO" if p and q are rational numbers.

Comment: "The smallest field"...over **what** ? Meaning: in what ring does the polynomial $\;f(x)\;$ live?

Comment: If it would make things any clearer, I could define F as the smallest sub-field of the field of all the complex numbers, which contains all the roots of f(x).

Comment: No, it doesn't @Garabed: from what field are the coefficients of the polynomial taken?

Comment: p and q belong to the field of all real numbers.

Comment: I also observe that there is this $\;p^x\;$ term which seems to be $\;px\;$ , otherwise $\;f(x)\;$ is not a polynomial at all.

Comment: @Timbue: I am very sorry for the way my "polynomial" got screwed up. f(x) should appear as "x^2+p*x+q". The "p" is a coefficient and is not supposed to be raised to the xth power. My question is whether one can find an example of two real numbers p and q, such that a field F containing the roots of f(x) is "formally real"-even if f(x) has no real roots. This will happen, of course, if and only if 4q is greater than the square of p.

Comment: I already answered your question: no, it's not possible as the only non-trivial algebraic extension of the real numbers are the complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your last comment:

But then $\;f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\;$ and thus its two (non-real, as given) roots are a conjugate pair $\;z\,,\,\,\overline z\;$ , and the only algebraic non-trivial extension of $\;\Bbb R\;$ is the complex $\;\Bbb C\;$, so no: $\;F=\Bbb C\;$ is not formally real.

Comment: Let the two non-real roots of f(x) be z(1) and z(2) and let Q be the field of all the rational numbers. I think of F as being obtained by first adjoining z(1) to Q to form the the field F(1) and then adjoining z(2) to F(1) to form the field F. Does your reasoning still imply that F can never be formally real? What if, for example, z(1)=a+bi and z(2)=a-bi where a,b are algebraically independent transcendental real numbers? How can a finite sum of squares of non-zero elements of F be equal to zero?

Comment: The case $\;p,q\in\Bbb Q\;$ wasn't taken into account: you specifically said in that case you already have the answer, so I'm assuming $\;p\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;\;or\;\;q\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$, and then $\;\Bbb R(z)\cong\Bbb C\;$ for any complex non-real $\;z\;$ , as noted.

Comment: Certainly, if one adjoins any non-real complex number to R, the resulting field is C, which is clearly not "formally real". But my field F is obtained by successively adjoining each of a pair of non-real conjugate complex numbers to Q-not to R. It is easy to construct examples of such fields F which are also not "formally real". My quesion was whether any such fields F could be "formally real". Q comes into it because every non-empty sub-field of C contains Q as a subset.

Comment: But why to $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ?! You yourself said several times the coefficients are real **and** the case where both coefficients are rational is already dealt with!

Comment: It seems that I have really messed up the way in which I worded my

Comment: It seems that I have really messed up the way in which I worded my original question and I am truly sorry for all the confusion it seems to have caused. Let me make one more attempt to get it right. Let F be a subfield of C obtained by successively adjoining to Q any pair of non-real conjugate complex numbers. Can F ever be "formally real"?